# Internet Connection Sharing after Windows 10 fall creators update hangs on "Starting"

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I've installed the update on a machine and after it the machine got very unstable.
(services not starting up many errors and warnings in the eventvwr)

Most problems seam to be related to double items in DCOM Config (Component services) like shellservicehost and runtimebroker.
The biggest issue that is bothering me is that the Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) service is in a constant "Starting" mode and never will start.

Because of the problems I reverted windows 10 back to a previous version. 
At first this seam to completely work. 
But then after the first reboot the ICS service was hanging again and I notice some errors about DCOM Activation in the eventvwr. So I took ownership in the registery of those appids and then added the local activation right in component services in this case on shellservicehost.
And again after a rebooot the ICS was starting and the world looked great again.

But today the ICS service is again in a never ending starting mode but now there are no warnings/or errors in the eventvwr.

I restarted several times but today to no avail. 
So I'm out of thoughts here does anybody have a good idea how to get the ICS started again?

Thank you

--Update
Because reverting windows did not solve my issue I decided to reinstall the fall creators update.
After the install I again got the DCOM activation errors that I fixed by giving the correct permissions.

So to be very specific the only issue left is the Internet Connection Sharing Service that cannot be started. It will hang in the "Starting" mode.

There are no more relevant messages in the eventwr.

So the question is now can anybody come up with a possible reason for the ICS not starting up that I can investigate?

Comment: I'm just wondering if you used Windows System Restore to revert OS back to the previous point?

Comment: Hi, No I used the recovery option to go back to previous version of windows described here: https://betanews.com/2017/10/20/how-to-rollback-and-uninstall-windows-10-fall-creators-update/

Comment: this was [discussed some time ago on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/1261114/174557)

Comment: Hi Magic nice one that post pointed me to the solution (for now) To get ICS running again I had to: - Turn firewall off and then reset windows defender firewall. After this the ICS service started at once. Can you please post your  answer as a real answer so I can mark it as such? Thank you for your help. Lets see if this solution survives the next reboots too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others to find the answer easier.
The solution was provided by @magicandre1981 in the comment section above referring to: [Superuser article](https://superuser.com/a/1261114/174557)
For me the part that worked was:

1. Disable the firewall
2. Reset windows defender firewall

After the above steps the ICS started at once!
Also after rebooting all is good again.

Answer (score 0):

This article helped me to solve the issue:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/mobile-hotspot-feature-not-working-after-fall/4c9c517e-e590-4096-ad87-d10ae4a6a219

Basically, you need to restore Windows Firewall settings to default.

Answer (score 0):

The freeware tool cFosICS manages Windows Internet Connection Sharing.
It comes with additional commands to fix the Windows 10 bug which may stop Internet Connection Sharing from working after a reboot.

See details here:
https://www.cfos.de/en/cfosspeed/cfosics.htm